# word-wrap break-word does not work in this example

Tags: html, css

I cannot get word-wrap to work with this example...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<table style="table-layout:fixed;">
<tr>
<td style="word-wrap: break-word; width:100px;">ThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrap</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

I remembered reading that a layout had to be specified (which I did), but beyond that I'm not sure what I have to do to get this to work.  I really would like this to work in Firefox.  Thanks.

EDIT:
Failed in Chrome 19 and Firefox 12, it works in IE8.
I tried doctype strict and transitional, neither worked.

Comment: Have you tried adding a DOCTYPE so that the browser doesn't run in IE5.5 mode?

Comment: Yes, a doctype does not appear to work.  I tried strict and transitional.

Comment: One thing the others don't seem to mention, you might have to put white-space back to normal if it's inherited.

Comment: this `white-space` comment worked for me and this should be a legitimate answer

Answer (score 133, accepted):

### *Mozilla Firefox* solution

Add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the style of your `td`.

### **Webkit based browsers (*Google Chrome*, *Safari*, ...) solution**

Add:

```
display: inline-block;
word-break: break-word;
```

to the style of your `td`.

***Note:***
Mind that, as for now, `break-word` is not part of the standard specification for webkit; therefore, you might be interested in employing the `break-all` instead. This alternative value provides a undoubtedly drastic solution; however, it conforms to the standard.

### ***Opera* solution**

Add:

```
display: inline-block;
word-break: break-word;
```

to the style of your `td`.

The previous paragraph applies to Opera in a similar way.

Comment: This is not the same as word-wrap:break-word; With word-break:break-all "Word breaks may be inserted between any character"

Comment: This is not a solution, but an **alternative** that works in a rather extreme way (break ALL)

Comment: Not Working for Safari 5.1.7..!! How this can be achieved?

Comment: Firefox: The inline block approach causes the <td>'s to be stacked, which isn't what I wanted.  The break-all as described in the next answer works very well.

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome, `word-break:break-word` worked while `word-wrap:break-word` did not.

Comment: `ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
 word-break: break-word;
}` Not working

Answer (score 87):

Word-Break has nothing to do with `inline-block`.

Make sure you specify `width` and notice if there are any overriding attributes in parent nodes. Make sure there is not `white-space: nowrap`.

see [this](https://codepen.io/ourway/pen/vYYdOay) codepen

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <style scoped>
    .parent {
      width: 100vw;
    }

    p {
      border: 1px dashed black;
      padding: 1em;
      font-size: calc(0.6vw + 0.6em);
      direction: ltr;
      width: 30vw;
      margin:auto;
      text-align:justify;
      word-break: break-word;
      white-space: pre-line;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      -ms-word-break: break-word;
      word-break: break-word;
      -ms-hyphens: auto;
      -moz-hyphens: auto;
      -webkit-hyphens: auto;
      hyphens: auto;
    }


    }
  </style>
  <div class="parent">

    <p>
      Note: Mind that, as for now, break-word is not part of the standard specification for webkit; therefore, you might be interested in employing the break-all instead. This alternative value provides a undoubtedly drastic solution; however, it conforms to
      the standard.

    </p>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank god! white-space: nowrap was the solution for me. how TH are there so many properties for doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes this answer is helpful. 
white-space:nowrap might be inherited and cause problems. 
It should be set to a different value. In my case I set it to white-space:break-spaces. You should also be able to set to the value to "unset" without any problems; assuming word-break or overflow-wrap is set

Comment: In my case white-space: nowrap was causing the problem. I don't know why. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 54):

Use this code ([taken from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)) that will work on all browser

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;

-ms-word-break: break-all;
/* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
word-break: break-all;
/* Instead use this non-standard one: */
word-break: break-word;

/* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
-ms-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

Comment: @SunnyS.M: Not Working for Safari 5.1.7..!! How this can be achieved?

Comment: how about hiding the off screen characters instead;

Comment: This got me over the finish line, thanks!

Answer (score 28):

```
max-width: 100px;
white-space: break-spaces;
```

Comment: white-space: break-spaces; also works with display: flex; and a margin to contain your text inside a container and break where necessary. only solution that worked in my case. thank you Rubel!

Answer (score 9):

This combination of properties helped for me:

```css
display: inline-block;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: normal;
line-break: strict;
hyphens: none;
-webkit-hyphens: none;
-moz-hyphens: none;
```

Comment: The Snippet provided is not working for Safari 5.1.7. How to fix it for Safari

Comment: this worked for me in mobile, safari issue. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

to get the smart break (break-word) work well on different browsers, what worked for me was the following set of rules:

```
#elm {
    word-break:break-word; /* webkit/blink browsers */
    word-wrap:break-word; /* ie */
}
-moz-document url-prefix() {/* catch ff */
    #elm {
        word-break: break-all; /* in ff-  with no break-word we'll settle for break-all */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> This code is also working:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<table style="table-layout:fixed;">
<tr>
<td style="word-break: break-all; width:100px;">ThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrapThisStringWillNotWrap</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Comment: The problem with break-all is it doesn't try breaking on spaces first.

Answer (score 1):

`word-wrap` property work's with `display:inline-block`:

```
display: inline-block;
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 100px;
```

Answer (score 1):

- `inline-block` is of no use in this scenario

SOLUTION

- `word-break: normal|break-all|keep-all|break-word|initial|inherit;`
  Simple Answer to your doubt is Use above and make sure `white-space: nowrap` nowhere used.

NOTE FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING:

- `word-wrap`/`overflow-wrap` is used to break words that overflow their container
- `word-break` property breaks all words at the end of a line, even those that would normally wrap onto another line and wouldn’t overflow their container.
- `word-wrap` is the historic and nonstandard property. It has been renamed to `overflow-wrap` but remains an alias, browsers must support in future. Many browsers (especially the old ones) don’t support `overflow-wrap` and require `word-wrap` as a fallback (which is supported by all).
- If you want to please the W3C you should consider associate both in your CSS. If you don’t, using `word-wrap` alone is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**The below set of CSS worked for me:**

```
                word-break: normal;
                line-break: strict;
                hyphens: none;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just specify the width of the container to be 100 and then add `display: block`.

```
<div class="parent"><span>dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text </span></div>
.parent
{
width:100%;
display:block
}
```