# word-wrap is not a known CSS property name

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

i'm trying to wrap a textbox but i'm getting that word-wrap is not a know css property name and it's not working so how can i fix it?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cnt_content">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cnt_content" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cnt_content") %>'  wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="cnt_content" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cnt_content") %>'></asp:Label> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
                <ItemStyle Width="800px" wrap="true" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

note that my textbox is in a gridview and i'm working on asp.net using vb.net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819390/css-word-wrap-not-working-as-expected?

Comment: i tried word-break instead of word-wrap and i'm getting the same error for the word-break

Comment: where are you getting this error?

Comment: I think you will find its just because of the CSS setting you have selected... at the top of VS there should be a dropdown to select which version of CSS you are using.

Comment: read the answer on this aswell, the comment where by the element must have a layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997223/word-wrapbreak-word-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.goto options in Visual studio.
2.select Text-editor.
3.select CSS
4.select Miscellaneous
5.Under detect errors tick that aswarning check box.
6.Now your error will become a warning in Visual studio.
7.IN browser yopu will get the result.
```

Comment: i don't have css under text-editor... i have only basic and html

Comment: which version of visual studio

Comment: visual studio 2010 version 10.0.40219.1

Comment: it's working for me when it's a simple textbox but mine is in a gridview... it's not working !!

Comment: So give cssClass = "some name".then write css for textbox seperately.Moreover it doesnt matter,css dont block compilation.u just untick that option for detect errors in css...Try to find it..

Comment: i've already tried this and still nth ! okay it's getting me insane !

Comment: visual studio 2010 professional or ultimate or ?...tell this one i ll fix for yu

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to using this is 
    word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: ok i changed it to word-wrap: break-word; but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Try to close your css file in VWD IDE and re-compile the error will go away.  Source - http://forums.asp.net/t/1438035.aspx/1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using asp.net's own `TextBox` `WordWrap` property.

```
<asp:TextBox Wrap="True|False" />
```

`TextMode` property to "`Multiline`"

Its working for me

[image]

Comment: The values permitted for this attribute do not include 'True|False'

Comment: Have you written both of them ? use one of them either true or false.

Comment: Have you set the textbox property "TextMode" to multiline?

Comment: it's working for me when it's a simple textbox but mine is in a gridview... it's not working !!

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cnt_content">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="cnt_content" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cnt_content") %>'  wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate> 
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:Label ID="cnt_content" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cnt_content") %>'></asp:Label> 
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                    <ItemStyle Width="800px" wrap="true" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, Visual Studio does not understand word-wrap property for Div.So it gives you green line.! So run your page & see output with  `<div style="word-wrap:break-word;">`

Comment: Why are you using width="700px" TextMode="MultiLine" properties? Try with deleting them.!