# word-wrap or word-break in Firefox won't work

Tags: html, css

`word-wrap:break-word;` and `word-break:break-all;` won't work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5bNq/5/

They do in Chrome tho... Any ideas?
Suggestions from this questions didn't work out: [word-wrap break-word does not work in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743763/word-wrap-break-word-does-not-work-in-this-example)

Comment: "The word-wrap property is no longer part of the CSS3 specification. It’s been replaced by the overflow-wrap property. You can read more about this and some other related properties here: New CSS3 Properties to Handle Text and Word Wrapping. With that in mind, I still recommend you use it, and place the overflow-wrap property in the same block of CSS, for future proofing." http://www.impressivewebs.com/word-wrap-css3/

Comment: adding overflow-wrap won't help, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

general here is the solution I am your code wrapped in a div class break-word

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C5bNq/77/)

**CSS**

```
.break-word {
-ms-word-break: break-all;
-ms-word-wrap: break-all;
-webkit-word-break: break-word;
-webkit-word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
}
```

Comment: If I do this, the scrollbar is removed, but the text is not breaking.

Comment: you should better to reconsider its markup because it will alter slightly and removing something I have achieved the desired results and that more white-space: pre; The text appears with all the gaps and transfers as they were added by the developer to code HTML. If the string is too long to fit in the browser window, it will be added to the horizontal scroll bar.