# List goes outside of my sidebar panel panel-primary

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My sidebar content is going over my panel. How do I prevent this from happening? 
I have created an example demonstrating this here: http://www.bootply.com/Du7RVsHh6H
Is there a bootstrap class that already handles this behavior or do I have to create a custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the class `panel-primary`.

Edit: You may also need to add `display: inline-block;` for it to display properly, citing this SO post:

[word-wrap break-word does not work in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743763/word-wrap-break-word-does-not-work-in-this-example)

Comment: Thank you this fixed it!  Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

add word-warp to ".panel-primary"

```
.panel-primary {
    border-color: #337ab7;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will actually use this as well and add it to the bootstrap class.