# paragraph text does not wrap correctly when in a mobile view - (CSS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

[Issue at hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS3jd.png)

My `<P>` tag text does not wrap correctly when viewed on mobile.

I am asking for a method of wrapping `<P>` tag text in a way that is mobile friendly.

*CSS Below*

```
margin-top: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 600px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
```

As you can see I have tried to use `word-wrap: break-word;` with no success.
***Any help or suggestions??***

Comment: Does this answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743763/word-wrap-break-word-does-not-work-in-this-example

Comment: Yes, this has solved my issue! thanks.

Comment: OK - closing as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***

```
display: inline-block;
word-break: break-word;
```

Fixes the issue on web-kit based browsers.